# Why compgen needs escaping here?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

There is some interesting behavior of `compgen -W` when I use single quotes inside double quotes (look how the last argument and output differ from command to command):

```
$ compgen -W "a\'b1 a\'b2" -- "a'"
a'b1
a'b2
$ compgen -W "a\'b1 a\'b2" -- "a'b"
$ compgen -W "a\'b1 a\'b2" -- "a\'b"
a'b1
a'b2
```

Why does the third command need a `\` before a `'` to get completion options, but the first command doesn't? It took me hours to find out this fact while debugging my completion script. Is this a bug, or is there any explanation why it has to work this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the way `compgen` deals with quote characters and escape characters in the target. In effect, it takes a very literal view of what completion might mean.

Let's consider something like the first case, but where the possible words don't have any special characters:

```
ab1
ab2
```

In bash, you could type the first of these words in any of the following ways (amongst others):

```
ab1
a'b'1
a''b1
a'b1'
```

So both `ab1` and `ab2` are possible completions of `a'`. And that's what `compgen` returns.

Now, let's go back to the actual targets in the question:

```
a'b1
a'b2
```

The first of these could be typed in either of these ways (amongst others):

```
a\'b1
a''\'b1
```

but it cannot be typed like this:

```
a'\''b1
```

So all of the following can be completed to either of the targets:

```
a
a'
a\
```

But the following cannot be

```
a'b
```